# Converting an AC Bookshelf Stereo to Use DC Batteries (e.g. Power Tool Batteries)

Tags: power-supply, converter

Summary of my Goal: Convert a standard AC-powered "bookshelf-style stereo" to use 1 or more of the power tool-style 18V DC batteries.

I would like to use (up to 4) 18V 2.0AH batteries like these:

[image]

... with adapters like these:

[image]

...to power the internals of something like this:

[image]

If this is possible, I'll be tearing the stereo case apart, stripping out the cassette and CD changer mechanism if possible, and will use it for just the tuner and amp.

Main question(s):

1. Is this feasible? (assuming I have up to 4 of these batteries available)
2. if so, how can this be achieved?  What part(s) would I need to order (or what things would I need to do to the stereo) in order to achieve this in a way that won't break the bank?

I have a rudimentary knowledge of how electronics work, but nowhere near the skills to understand what's required to power an AC device off of a DC source. I can solder components, etc. but lack knowledge beyond that.

I know I could just go buy a bluetooth speaker or something like that but I'm looking to expand knowledge and skills through this exercise. I guess I just need a point in the right direction (if it's in-fact feasible).

Some clarifications:

- Stereo has a hard-wired power cord.
- ...which I guess means it has an internal PSU
- It doesn't take batteries at all

Comment: I'm guessing that stereo has an external power adapter (a "wall wart" or "power brick"). If you take a look at the adapter, what does it say the output voltage is?

Comment: If the unit has an inbuilt PSU, probably going to be difficult, as that PSU will supply all the different voltages different parts of the unit needs. If it has a single external powerbrick connection, then your life is easier. Measure the voltages at the power supply inputs to the tuner and amp that you want to keep, then go about generating those from batteries.

Comment: If you're serious about this project, first find the schematics of that stereo. That'll detail the power supply voltages.

Comment: If there's no external DC adaptor, but it's enough like a boom box to take batteries, then just replicate the voltage that stack of batteries would give you.

Comment: Added a few clarifications to the question based on the comments.  Sounds like first step is finding schematics. I'll work on that over the next week or so, and post back if/when I find them.

Comment: It can be done, but it will most likely not be easy or feasible, but without schematics it will be difficult to anyone to guess. And basically you are asking what to buy which is off topic.

Comment: Easiest but most expensive solution would be DC-AC inverter. Technically best would be to open it up and find out what voltage rail(s) it has on the secondary and try to feed into those.

Comment: @GWR It looks to me as though [this](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/683449/Jvc-Mx-Kb4.html) may be the service manual for it. But it's possible I'm wrong. Perhaps you can decide?

Comment: Oh man, why????

Comment: @Andyaka - I know. It's stupid. But thought I could use it as a learning project. But it's sounding as though it may not be worth it

Comment: Find out the internal DC specs 1st

Comment: You should figure out power requirements by looking at the power supply spec (usually written on the appliance) - that may help figure out the unfeasibility of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what I believe may be the service manual for it. It looks to me like the JVC MX-KB4, from your image. If so, then the manual is available [here](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/683449/Jvc-Mx-Kb4.html).

From that, I extracted the power supply schematic using an open source tool ([XPDF](https://www.xpdfreader.com/about.html)) to generate the high resolution image below:

[image]

It's spec'd to provide \$180\:\text{W}\$ per channel. And the fusing appears to confirm this, arranged for a maximum of about \$420\:\text{W}\$.

If I'm reading things right, this means one of your batteries would last about 5 minutes at full power output. All four might survive for 20 minutes. At lower power output, likely longer. But I don't think this is a good match, even assuming you could design a DC-DC circuit with associated necessary layout and dissipation issues handled well.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good candidate for this unit because there are multiple supplies which exceed the voltage on the battery, making conversion difficult even for experts. https://manualmachine.com/jvc/mxj980v/3254989-schematic/

Try to learn how it works for your 1st task from reading the schematics. then when you understand, make a list of specs for V, I and ripple.